# Google Map Click To Show HTML Form Fields

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I have the following JS code which allows the user to add a single or multiple markers to a map.

```
(function add() {
var map, geocoder;

        window.onload = function() {

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location, 
      map: map
  });

  map.setCenter(location);
}
})();
```

This is part of a form which allows the user to add more details about the marker or markers that they have created and a cut down version the HTML code for this is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/addfindsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addfinds.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="add" id="add">
<div>
<label for="address">

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="left">
    <label>
    <div align="center">Location Name<br />
        <input name="locationname" type="text" id="locationname" />
    </div>
    </label>
  </p>
  <label>Description
  <input name="description" type="text" id="description" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</div>
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone perhaps tell me please how I may go about hiding the fields, (in this example the field 'description') and the 'submit' button until a marker is created on the map and then once the submit button is pressed the fields and button are hidden until the next marker is created.

Many thanks

Chris

**UPDATE**

Hi, many thanks for the code.

I must be something incredibly stupid here, but I've added the code you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've changed the Javascript line to :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
 $("#add").show(); $("#add").submit(function(event){$(this).hide(); return false;});   
placeMarker(event.latLng);
```

and the CSS to:

```css
body {

    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: auto;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
    outline-style: none;
    right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}
form {
    #add display: none; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 14px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#map {
    width: 795px;
    height: 503px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: 215px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Could you perhaps tell me where I've gone wrong please?

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: I noted that I'm using jQuery. You need to add jQuery to your page before your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the elements initially:

```css
#add {
    display: none;
}
```

Then use JavaScript (example uses jQuery for brevity) to show/hide the fields.

Inside

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

}
```

Add:

```
$("#add").show();
$("#add").submit(function(event){$(this).hide(); return false;});
```

Here's a jsfiddle example (really rough though, no styling) http://jsfiddle.net/phKEt/

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying and for setting up the jsfiddle. The line for the event marker was missing so I've added that in. The strange thing is, is that I can get it to work in jsfiddle but not through macromedia or from my server. I've never seen this before. Have you any ideas please? Many thanks Chris

Comment: UPDATE I've got this to work. I guess it helps if you download 'jquery'. Apologies, it's been a long day. Many thanks for your time trouble and patience. Kind regards Chris.